# how solve build ruby 1.9.3-p327 error:EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m

Tags: ruby, build

when i build ruby-1.9.3-p327

## ./configure

## make

Error:
ossl_pkey_ec.c:In functin 'ossl_ec_group_initialize':
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816:error: 'EC_GROUP_new_curve_GF2m' undeclard (first use in this function)
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816:error: (Each undeclard indentifier is reported only once
ossl_pkey_ec.c:816 error:for each function it appearts in.)

Comment: What operating system? Which compiler? etc etc..

Comment: I use centos 6.4 I do this mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
curl --progress http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p392.tar.gz | tar xz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p392
./configure
make
make install

Answer (score 0):

It's a know issue, you need to patch it: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8384